# How to find the correct operators for an equation, using python?

Tags: python, math, equation

I am practicing python and I want to find the correct operators to find when the equation below equals 120
 35(operator) 5(operator) 20(operator) 5(operator) for example 35+5+20+35 = 120

I have written this script in python but it does not seem to produce. The catch is that I can't use division('/'). Brackets can be included as well.

```
opr = ["+", "-", "*"]

for op1 in opr:
  for op2 in opr:
    for op3 in opr:
        testStr = "35" + op1 + "5" + op2 + "20" + op3 + "5"
        if eval(testStr) == 120:
            print(testStr)
            break
```

Comment: What does "does not seem to produce" mean?

Comment: Are you aware you put `"5"` instead of `"35"` at the end?

Comment: You have 35+5+20+35 in the text and 35, 5, 20, *5* in the code. Neither add up to 120. But if you fix that, you'll get a solution.

Comment: Yes, I am aware it would seem I have mistaken the description, the code however is correct. Produce meaning it doesn't come to any value, it doesn't print it doesn't break it actually just start and then terminate.

Comment: I tested your code by printing the testStr and its eval before your `if eval` line (e.g. `print("{0} = {1}".format(testStr, eval(testStr)))`.  user2357112 and Ken Shirriff are right; if you fix your typo, this code works.  (35*5-20-35=120)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your code so it would print the test string and result with every loop, and this is what I got:

```
35+5+20+5 evaluates to: 65
35+5+20-5 evaluates to: 55
35+5+20*5 evaluates to: 140
35+5-20+5 evaluates to: 25
35+5-20-5 evaluates to: 15
35+5-20*5 evaluates to: -60
35+5*20+5 evaluates to: 140
35+5*20-5 evaluates to: 130
35+5*20*5 evaluates to: 535
35-5+20+5 evaluates to: 55
35-5+20-5 evaluates to: 45
35-5+20*5 evaluates to: 130
35-5-20+5 evaluates to: 15
35-5-20-5 evaluates to: 5
35-5-20*5 evaluates to: -70
35-5*20+5 evaluates to: -60
35-5*20-5 evaluates to: -70
35-5*20*5 evaluates to: -465
35*5+20+5 evaluates to: 200
35*5+20-5 evaluates to: 190
35*5+20*5 evaluates to: 275
35*5-20+5 evaluates to: 160
35*5-20-5 evaluates to: 150
35*5-20*5 evaluates to: 75
35*5*20+5 evaluates to: 3505
35*5*20-5 evaluates to: 3495
35*5*20*5 evaluates to: 17500
```

As you can see, it never evaluates to 120.